# An error occurred while provisioning your stack:functionlog - /aws/lambda/Serverless/function already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I get this error when I try to do sls deploy:

> An error occurred while provisioning your stack:functionlog      -
>   /aws/lambda/Serverless/function already exists.

This is because the framework version changed...

- previous version = 1.5.1
- present version = 1.8.0

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I dont see the question here

Comment: how to resolve error

Comment: 1. uninstall server less npm  
2. install server less @ particular version (you want).
3. run as usual